# Why would Dany enter into an alliance with these characters?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S6E7 of Game of Thrones we are told that

> Yara and Theon are looking towards an alliance with Dany

Why would Dany ever agree to that proposal? What do they have to offer her? Surely she'd take their allegiance but they don't have any means to advance Dany's quest, do they.

Am I missing something here? This looks like more characters heading for certain death. Or are we going to theorise a few more Targaryen bastards are about to be revealed?

Answer (score 11):

In S6E6, after Danys speech, she's declaring that

> they will need "a thousand ships" to cross the narrow sea. How convenient that one of the best fleets in Westeros is already on their way to her.

Here's the actual dialog:

> Dany: How many ships will I need to bring my khalasar to Westeros?
>
>  Daario: Dothraki and all their horses, the Unsullied, the Second Sons. 1,000 ships easily. Probably more.

Comment: - Hey Daario, how many ships will we need to get over to Westeros? - I dunno, whatever Euron said last episode

Comment: Iron Fleet is pretty fearsome but it is comprised of longships except a few bigger vassals. They are no match for Southern Galleys and dromonds as Stannis proved when he smashed the Iron Fleet. Not really the best fleet imo. +1 anyways

Comment: @Aegon edited the answer per your wise words. Also, for reference: "It is one of the three most powerful fleets of Westeros, along with the royal fleet of the crownlands and the Redwyne fleet of the Arbor."  http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Iron_Fleet

Comment: Yes, that's why Euron is going there. Yara and Theon don't have anywhere close to the mentioned number of ships. They are just a few renegades. They don't have the entire iron fleet, just a small fraction.

Comment: @user1129682 actutally, they are in possess of quite a considerable amount of the standing iron fleet. Euron is building new ships as we speak! Also, this storyline is show only, so there's no proof from the books. In the books, it's Victarion - by Eurons orders - who's sailing to Dany with around 90-100 ships.

Comment: If Yara and Theons support was that big they wouldn't need to run from Euron. They could simply refuse him as king or at least have the leverage to remain alive, well and high among the iron born. Or they could just kill him. Euron killing Balon didn't have any negative effects on his career either. And then he can proclaim publicly "Where are my niece and nephew? Let's go murder them!" They can't have a sizable armada. That wouldn't really make sense. Much less than anything else we have seen so far.

Comment: It could be that Yara has the support of a large number (though maybe not the majority) of the active sailors, since she's served with them, led them into battle, earned their respect, etc... but much less against the island population, the shipbuilders, etc who are chicken-hawkish and more old-fashioned about women.  She had enough to take a huge chunk of the best of the currently standing Iron Fleet (which could have been partly from inattention, as many of the opposed soldiers were attending Euron's drowning), at least, that much was outright stated.  Euron has to build more to catch up.

Comment: So we believe that Yara and Theon are sailing about with 50+ ships? I was more under the impression these would be 20-30 ships, most of them small like those they used to raid the stony shore and poorly manned, because we are talking about revolting against your newly elected king of your home, family and friends. Let it be 50 ships. How much sympathy will Dany have for 2 renegades with 50 ships, when Euron arrives with hundret of ships and asks for their heads as his price? A couple of ships won't do anything for Yara and Theon.

Comment: @user1129682 Fifty ships doesn't seem like enough to haul Dany's army (+ their horses, + supplies, + families/servants) across the sea. One possibility is that with help from Yara's fleet they'll commandeer more ships from other cities in Essos. The other question is where Dany can find a safe harbor in Westeros? How will she take cities and castles? There's no evidence the Unsullied and Dothraki are trained/equipped for long sieges. Suppose that's where her dragons come in handy. :)

Comment: @RobertF: I know, that's my point, Yara and Theon, do not in the slightest have the means to advance Dany's campaign and everything they do have is dwarfed by everything Euron has to offer, including a safe harbour in Westeros. What do they have that makes them believe Dany will favour them over Euron, once he makes it to Mereen?

Comment: @user1129682 Yara will have have ships when and where Dany needs them. I'm not certain Dany will want to wait in Mereen another year for Euron's promised fleet. It could take Euron many months or years to build a sizable fleet of ships, assuming the Iron Isles have the resources to build & crew another fleet (which seems implausible, especially after the losses from campaigning in the North). Building a fleet is a huge endeavor, and I get the impression Greyjoy is not a wealthy House.

Answer (score 1):

Dany wants to attack Westeros. To do that she needs a fighting force in Westeros. So far the plan has always been to move that fighting force to Westeros by sea.

The Greyjoys have a number of ships, and a number of men. If used as a fighting force, their numbers are small. While the amount of ships and men is small, there is value there. Yet, the far more valuable thing they can offer is a number of experienced men who can teach her people how to build ships, how to sail ships, and how naval combat works.

While there is an alternative source of Greyjoy ships, Dany doesn't know that yet. Once a deal has been struck it can't be undone without harming one's reputation.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand the fact that Daenerys would surely sympathize with Yara, don't forget that she (Yara) aims to name herself queen of the Iron Islands. Dany likely won't support her in gaining that title since her current goal is to take Westeros back and rule as queen of *all 7* kingdoms. Yara and Theon have more to offer her than you think. Remember that they took all of the *best and fastest* ships from the Iron Fleet. While they may not be nearly enough to transport Dany's troops, they can likely outmaneuver most enemy ships and be useful in the actual naval combat as well as moving troops quickly. Yara's men also have great knowledge of the sea and coast along their stretch of territory and are fierce warriors themselves. Add to that their strong sailing skills and you have a nice little package to offer. Add to that the fact that Euron can't even be trusted by his own kin and is power-hungry, and the decision is easy. I assume she won't give Yara nearly as much as she is receiving, but being on the Dragon Queen's good side can't hurt.

Comment: Wouldn't be so sure of that. As Renly said, "King is only a word". Daenerys can allow Yara to call herself Queen as long as she does fealty to Daenerys and answers her calls to arms.

Comment: Can one call oneself a queen if one owes fealty to a queen? When the King in the North bowed to the Conquering Dragon King, he became the Lord Paramount and Warden of the North. Moreover, to me, it's really an issue of maintaining respect and power. If she allows one woman from a tiny part of her kingdom to prance about & call herself queen, it would inevitably lead to others doing so, diminishing the power of the title, in my opinion. It seems politically unsound. It also seems to me a great boon on Dany's part for a largely disparate contribution. (P.S. saw your profile. LotR + GoT = <3333)

Comment: There is already precedent for it. Dornish rulers are allowed to call themselves princes and princesses 9. Renly offered the same privilege to Robb Stark.

Comment: P.s. Dornish Kings and Queens called themselves Princes and Princesses. Their culture does not have kings or queens

Comment: Ah, but Dorne was the only part of the Seven Kingdoms that the Targaryens were unable to defeat.. I would also note that, no matter the culture, prince/princess does not equal king/queen. Anyhow, with Dorne being folded into the culture of the rest of the Seven Kingdoms, though prince and princess might be THEIR highest title, it is not for anyone else. Besides, everyone else considers it a courtesy title only. Renly offering the same to Robb Stark is a different matter. A.) Robb Stark (and the North, by extension) was a potential HUGE ally to Renly, who really had no claim to the throne.

Comment: B.) Renly was willing to make compromises such as this, whereas I think Dany would balk: she's been fighting for her 'birthright' for years, to be QUEEN of Westeros. She's more of an 'I'm your Queen, you owe me fealty regardless' rather than someone who will  bargain for what is hers by rights. Now, if Yara wants to call herself 'Princess' maybe Dany would be alright, but I don't see that. Yara is no 'princess' and she just doesn't offer quite enough to bargain for the honor.

Comment: How do you consider westeros seven kingdoms if you don't think dorne is a kingdom? Rhoynar always called their monarchs princes and princesses. Even before nymeria's landing. When they came to dorne, dornish started calling their rulers Prince instead of king. There were kings like king vorian dayne, king yronwood in dorne before nymeria and rhoynar came. Renly didn't need Robb. He had a hundred thousand soldiers. Robb had twenty-five. He was just avoiding unnecessary war with northmen.

Comment: Daenerys has made more compromises from day one than any other character. Just start analyzing her rule of meereen.

Comment: My point was that once Dorne was brought into the fold, the titles of 'Prince' and 'Princess' ceased to be that of the highest ranking ruler, as now they had 'kings' and 'Queens' to whom they owed fealty. In essence, though they weren't referred to any differently, their rank dropped a notch nonetheless, and as far as the rest of the nobility was concerned, they were granted these titles as a courtesy, with no additional power than, say, Lord Arryn. Sure, Renly didn't NEED Robb, but it would be N error not to pacify him; he'd proven what he could do on the battlefield. He likely wouldn't win,

Comment: But he could make Renly bleed if he chose. AAR, if Renly simply 'avoided' Robb without offering something, even if he won the crown, he would still have a Northern revolt to deal with. Robb couldn't back down once his bannermen decided to fight for their 'King in the North.' Good luck turning your troops around from King's Landing and marching North (A territory spanning as much land as the rest of the Kingdoms together), in the cold, in the winter. After years of fighting. Robb/Renly is not comparable to Yara/Daenerys in this. It took Tyrion's presence for any REAL compromise to happen.